# Analytical evaluation of an improper integral involving a product of exponential and Bessel functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, residue-calculus

While I was elaborating on a fluid mechanics problem, I came across improper (infinite) integrals of the form
$$
I_{m,n} (\alpha, \rho) = 
\int_0^\infty \frac{q^n e^{-q}}{1+\alpha q} J_m(\rho q) \mathrm{d} q, 
$$
wherein $n \in \{1,2\}$ and $m \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.
In addition, $\alpha \ge 0$ and $\rho \ge 0$.

For $\alpha = 0$, those integrals can easily be evaluated.
I was wondering whether there exists an approach to tackle those integrals when $\alpha \ne 0$.
Any hints or advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Include your attempts. Otherwise this question will get closed.

Comment: @vitamind is this a very recently established policy?

Comment: No. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) for more information.

Comment: @vitamind i will work on that meanwhile someone else will perhaps help with a hint

Comment: What is the $\alpha=0$ result?

Comment: @user619894 can readily be obtained using Laplace transforms. Maple/Mathematica should also be able to do it i guess

Comment: The reason I am asking is because you can replace the denominator by $\int e^{-\lambda(1+\alpha q)}d\lambda$, bringing you to the $\alpha=0$ situation, for which you can then integrate the $dq$, but then you get the $d\lambda $ integration. If the $\alpha=0$ is simple, you have made progress.

Comment: The $\alpha=0$ case is actually known.
$$\int_0^\infty t^{\mu-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}J_\nu(zt)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\left(z/2\right)^\nu}{\lambda^{\mu+\nu}}\Gamma(\mu+\nu)~_{2}F_{1}\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\mu+\nu}{2},\frac{\mu+\nu+1}{2}\\
\nu+1
\end{matrix} \Bigg|\frac{-z^2}{\lambda^2}\right)$$
So i.e
$$I_{m,n}(0,\rho)=(m+n)!\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)^{m}~_{2}F_{1}\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{m+n}{2},\frac{m+n}{2}+1\\
m+1
\end{matrix} \Bigg|-\rho^2\right)$$

Source: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22 Identity 10.22.49

Comment: So, Not simple...

Comment: Not sure that this helps but $\int e^{-at}J_n(bt)dt=\frac{b^n}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a)^n}\Rightarrow I_{m,n} (\alpha, \rho) = 
\int_0^\infty \frac{q^n e^{-q}}{1+\alpha q} J_m(\rho q) dq$$=(-1)^m\Big(\frac{d}{d\alpha}\Bigr)^m\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\rho^me^{-a}da}{a^m\sqrt{(1+\alpha a)^2+\rho^2}(\sqrt{(1+\alpha a)^2+\rho^2}+1+\alpha a)^m}$

Comment: @user619894 It can actually be simplified in terms of fractions with square roots. For instance, $I_{2,1} = 3\rho \left( 1+\rho^2 \right)^{-5/2}$.